# Múltiple GroupJoin con LINQ Lambda a objetos

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

El tema es que he realizado una query en LINQ Lambda para asociar las tablas 'Suppliers' y 'Products' a la tabla 'Stocks'. Para ello me he visto obligado a utilizar un doble GroupJoin ya que con un simple Join el resultado no quedaba completo ya que en ocasiones hay líneas de stock que no contienen proveedor.

La query que he realizado es la siguiente:

```
Context.Stocks
.GroupJoin(Context.Suppliers, st => st.SupplierId, s => s.Id, (st, s) => new {st, s})
.SelectMany(st=> st.s.DefaultIfEmpty(), (st, s) => new {st.st, s})
.GroupJoin(Context.Products, sts => sts.st.ProductId, p => p.Id, (sts, p)=> new {sts, p})
.SelectMany(ext => ext.p.DefaultIfEmpty(), (ext, p) => new 
                   {ProductCode = ext.sts.st.ProductCode,
                   SupplierName = ext.sts.s.Name,
             ProductDescription = p.Description
                               ...})
```

Creo que la query funciona correctamente, ya que funciona y devuelve las líneas que la query que tenía preparada con Join's no devolvía.

Mis dudas son,

¿Esta la query correctamente formulada?

Mi duda es por qué después del DefaultIfEmpty() tengo que volver a declarar el tipo anónimo de este modo:

`(st, s) => new {st.st, s})`

¿De donde viene la asignación '**st.st**'? ¿Por que he de llamar a '**st.st**' en esa declaración del tipo anónimo y no a '**s.s**' también quedando así de la siguiente manera?

`(st, s) => new {st.st, s.s})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El usar `DefaultIfEmpty()` es porque estas conciderando que el join puede ser opcional, o sea seria como un `LEFT JOIN` entre las entidades, cuando no hay relacion resolvera el default

[Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Lo que no me queda claro es porque realizas un `SelectMany()` entre los dos `group joins` no veo que se anecesario

No seria mejor si la planteas con notacion linq, creo que quedaria mas entendible

```
var result = from stock in Context.Stocks
              join supplier in Context.Suppliers on stock.SupplierId equals supplier.Id
              join product in Context.Products on stock.ProductId equals product.Id
              select new {
                ProductCode = product.ProductCode,
                SupplierName = supplier.Name,
                ProductDescription = product.Description
              };
```

analiza si con la notacion linq no tienes el mismo resultado

**>>>¿De donde viene la asignación 'st.st'? ¿Por que he de llamar a 'st.st' en esa declaración del tipo anónimo y no a 's.s' también quedando así de la siguiente manera?**

El primer st viene de la definicion del `(st, s)`, mientras que el otro viene del `(st, s) => new {st, s}` que defines en el `GroupJoin()`
Lo que noto es que estas redefiniendo la salida en cada metodo, cuando podrias simplemente usar

```
.SelectMany(st=> st.s.DefaultIfEmpty())
```

[Enumerable.SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)

Recomendaria que vayas variando los nombres para ver como afectan al siguiente, de esta forma veras como se utilizan

```
.GroupJoin(Context.Suppliers, st => st.SupplierId, s => s.Id, (st, s) => new {stJoin1 = st, sJoin1 = s})
.SelectMany(st=> st.sJoin1.DefaultIfEmpty(), (st, s) => new {stMany1 = st.stJoin1, sMany1 = s})
```

algo como eso, al ir cambiando podras ver donde afecta